# Disable Language Packages in Zypper

Tags: software-installation, package-management, opensuse, zypper

I am an OpenSUSE user, which means that I use zypper as the main package manager. When I install *almost* anything, I get a package with the same name but with a *-lang* suffix that is `recommended` by zypper. However, I want to use english only (which is the default), so I don't want to install every language package available for every package I install.

How can I disable these language package *recommendations* ?

Comment: did you try zypper install --no-recommends pakage?

Comment: @taliezin: you don't get my point. I **want** recommendations, but not language packages recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

Find all the language packages:

```
rpmorphan -guess-custom "-lang$"
```

Delete them:

```
rpmorphan -guess-custom "-lang$" | xargs zypper rm
```

Add a lock to all packakes ending on -lang (prevents them from being reinstalled):

```
zypper al '*-lang'
```